# Json.Parse returns same string that was passed, not creating an array of objects as expected

Tags: json

I've even saw that this has been posted before, but the answer seemed vague and didn't help me. Parsing the json string just returns a string and doesn't create an object with properties. I'm sure I'm missing something or haven't properly set this up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Json string being returned from web service:

```
[{"RctId":1,"Name":"Function Room 8 Hour Charge"},{"RctId":2,"Name":"Function Room 4 Hour Charge"}]
```

Code:

```
var obj;
var re = xmlhttp.responseText;
obj = JSON.parse(re);

document.getElementById("dp").innerHTML = obj;
alert(obj[0].RctId);
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(obj);` line after `obj = JSON.parse(re);`. What do you see in a console?

Comment: make sure it is indeed a string. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xs7td15j/

Answer (score 0):

turns out I just needed to eval the reponsetext then it parsed just fine.

Comment: cold you please show what you did ?
and shouldn't JSON.parse() do the same thing with a valid JSON ?